# Problems getting function to run every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to create a notification system where whenever a new entry is made in the database,  a notification is seen by a user. On its own, the script loops through a mysql table  until a new entry is detected, then it stops the loop and displays a notification.

My intention was to modify the script so that after the notification, the function (check()) should be recalled every five seconds from when a new record is detected.

My problem is when i put the script in a time based loop(5 second interval), the loop seems to run indefinitely even when new records are inserted.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

```
<?php

$echo_time = time();
$interval = 5;
while(true){
 if ($echo_time + $interval >= time()){
  check();
  echo "$interval seconds have passed...";
  $echo_time = time(); // set up timestamp for next interval
}
// other uninterrupted code goes here.


function check()
{
 $timeStart = time();
 $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");       
 // Create connection
 $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','test');

 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
 die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );

 // select where item is new

 if(isset($_POST['timestamp'])){
    $timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];
 }else
 {
  // get current database time
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,'SELECT now() as now'));
  $timestamp = $row['now'];
 }
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE insertDate > '$timestamp'";

 $newData = false;
 $notifications = array();

 // loop while there is no new data and is running for less than 20 seconds
 while(!$newData && (time()-$timeStart)<20){

  // check for new data
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $notifications[] = $row;
     $newData = true;
     echo "<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $.sticky('The page has loaded!');
         var callnotification = function(){
         $.sticky('<b>A new Invoice has arrived!</b>');
         }
        callnotification;
       });
      </script>";
    }

   }

 // get current database time
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,'SELECT now() as now'));
 $timestamp = $row['now'];
 mysqli_close($con);

 }
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you use websockets for this instead of this pattern. You will massively increase your network traffic and demand on the web and database server if you have N users making a request every 5 seconds.

Comment: You are using an infinite while loop (while true), which you never terminate with a condition or a break statement.

Comment: I would have tried web sockets but its not an option with the server I am using. @sander any advice will help, eager to learn

Comment: @user3682205 you are trying to use long-polling for some wierd server-side pull requests. Please read those  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling. You shoud either use client-side pull OR use long-polling in the way it's meant to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using "setTimeout" function

for Eg:

```
var checkForNotification = function(){
   // ajax call to a function which check for a new notification
};

setTimeout(checkForNotification, 5000);
```